# expansion of exponential in terms of bessel function?

Tags: bessel-functions

I saw somewhere contains below formula.
$${e^{ikr\cos \left( \theta  \right)}} = \sum\limits_n {{i^n}{J_n}\left( {kr} \right){e^{ - in\theta }}} $$
I don't know if it is right. Does anyone know how to prove it? Or point to some references on this kind of expansions using bessel function?

Comment: A. Erdélyi et al., [Higher Transcendental Functions Vol. II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman_Manuscript_Project), give in 7.2.4 (27)
$$e^{iz \cos \phi} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty i^n e^{in\phi} J_n(z)$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion

Comment: @Chappers gammatester Thank you so much. Exactly what I want